# Ubuntu gives black screen on Built-in monitor but ok on external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, radeon

I've installed Ubuntu 23.10 (also tried 21.10 20.04 22.04 to no avail) using the safe graphics option. Every time I try to boot into Ubuntu, there is a few lines of code and then my monitor is on but it turns near black.
Until yesterday I thought the problem was my video card (Amd Radeon RX560 4gb) , then I plugged an external display. I could move my mouse and the cursor was visible. (Although the login screen was black only with a cursor , using the Enter key and my password I logged on to Ubuntu and I set the external display as the default). I have access to Ubuntu using the external monitor.
Another thing that I saw in the display settings was I couldn't change my built in display resolution and it was locked on 640x300 but my display was 1920x1080.
My pc specifications : (HP Eliteone G4X1)

```
Intel core i7 8700
Amd radeon RX560 
32gb ram
4gb vram
1tb SSD
```

also I've tried installing Amdgpu drivers (on 22.04) but when I rebooted Ubuntu was a command line instead of the gui